# Gazebo doesn't start (but RViz does)

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm quite new to ROS. I started out with the following robot: https://github.com/epfl-lasa/kuka-lwr-ros I got everything running (so far at least). But there is still an issue, namely RViz starts but Gazebo doesn't. The readme of the kuka-lwr-ros states: "If the Gazebo window does not open this is because a flag is set in the sim.launch file." but I really can't find this flag. The sim.launch looks like follows:

```
<include file="$(find lwr_launch)/launch/simulation.launch">
        <arg name="rviz_config"       value="$(find lwr_simple_example)/launch/rviz/rviz_config.rviz"/>
    <arg name="t1_limits"         value="false"/>
</include>
```

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318273/gazebo-doesn%27t-start-(but-rviz-does)/) by [steradiant](https://answers.ros.org/users/40427/steradiant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS, launch files can include other launch files.  The `sim.launch` file you gave here is doing that with the `<include file=...>` tag.  If you go to the file specified there ([simulation.launch](https://github.com/epfl-lasa/kuka-lwr-ros/blob/master/kuka_lwr/lwr_launch/launch/simulation.launch#L23)), you'll see the Gazebo flag you're looking for.

The README probably gave the wrong file to look in because the launch files have been refactored since then.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1